Angle between two lines formula edge case, coordinate geometry
If there are two non-vertical lines in the cartesian plane with slope as $m_1$ and $m$ with $\theta$ as the acute angle between them then we have,
$$
\tan(\theta) = \left|  \frac{m - m_1}{1 + m_1m} \right|
$$
If we know $\theta$ and $m_1$ then we can solve for $m$, but simplifying the formula in terms of $m$ we get
For positive value inside modulus:
$$
\tan(\theta) + m_1 + m(\tan(\theta)m_1 - 1) = 0
$$
For negative value inside modulus:
$$
\tan(\theta) - m_1 + m(\tan(\theta)m + 1) = 0
$$
What will be the value of m in the above cases if $\tan(\theta)m_1 = \pm1$ respectively, as the expressions become independent of $m$? I was tinkering and got that the line with slope $m$ could be the x-axis or the y-axis but I don't understand the reason for this. Thank you.

What is $m_2$ in the last equation?

My bad that was a typo, fixed it now

Square the equation to get
$$
\tan^2(\theta) =   \frac{m^2 - 2m_1m + m_1^2}{1 + 2m_1m+m_1^2m^2}.
$$
Since $\tan^2\theta m_1^2=1$, we get
$$2m(m_1+\frac1{m_1})=m_1^2 - \tan^2\theta$$
or
$$m=\frac{(m_1^2 - \tan^2\theta)m_1
}{2(m_1^2+1)}=\frac{m_1^2 - 1}{2m_1}.$$
The other $m$ is $\pm\infty.$  But,  it is lost in the solution.

Yes it is easy to see that for limits of $\pm \infty$ the value of $tan^2(\theta) = \frac{1}{m_1^2}$. Thanks for the insight of squaring the expression. If I don't get a better answer on this post till tomorrow then I will accept this one.

Thanks for the correction. @GameTimeWithAryan
